# Error when importing PyLab on 64 - bit windows and Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib

So I got numpy, scipy, IPython, and matplotlib working (I can import all four with "import _____)". However, I cannot get pylab to work. I've was under the impression that if I had the above I'd be able to import pylab. I wish I could understand these errors; they look like babel to me. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Any help is appreciated.

My error is as follows:

```
>>> from pylab import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 222, in <module>
    from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import axes
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 21, in <module>
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 122, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY, \
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\dateutil\rrule.py", line 18, in <module>
    from six import advance_iterator, integer_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

I'm using matplotlib 1.2.x. here's the link: [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ipython](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ipython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not an error message I've seen before, but six is a package which provides 2to3 support for Python versions.

You can get hold of six from [here](http://packages.python.org/six/).

It is usually installed as part of "base". There is a [Windows "base" package](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#base).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem by installing Python 2.x The graphing library [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html) doesn't support Python 3.x . [Few libraries do](http://python3wos.appspot.com/).

While version 3.0 was released four years ago, most users are better using Python 2.x because the community has yet to adopt 3.x universally. The Python devs [say so themselves](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3). Yes, this is embarrassing :\